# How to display nested JSON object in the form of table and rest JSON value as simple text

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to display nested JSON objects.

This is what I have done so far:

```
orders = [
  { "custname": "Jack   Smith", "mobile": "425361434", "location": "Sector  14", "slot": "12PM2PM", "value": 72.6, "items": [{ "prodcode": "PEP122", "quantity": 2 }, { "prodcode": "COK238", "quantity": 4 }] },
  { "custname": "Mary   Gomes", "mobile": "723476123", "location": "Sector  22", "slot": "4PM6PM", "value": 130.60, "items": [{ "prodcode": "SUN677", "quantity": 2 }, { "prodcode": "LUX831", "quantity": 4 }, { "prodcode": "DET810", "quantity": 1 }] },
  { "custname": "Tim    May", "mobile": "835099614", "location": "Pioneer   Chowk", "slot": "Before 10AM", "value": 705, "items": [{ "prodcode": "GAR004", "quantity": 6 }, { "prodcode": "RB0277", "quantity": 3 }, { "prodcode": "MIR411", "quantity": 2 }] }
];
function showAllOrder() {
  showtable();
}


function showtable() {

  for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {


    order = orders[i];

    var str = "<div><div class='cell22' onclick=clicked(0)>Product</div>";
    str = str + "<div class='cell22' onclick=clicked(1)>Qantity</div>";


    var len = orders[i].items.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      for (var x = 0; x <)
        //this value as simple text form above the table
        var cost = ("Coustomer Name :" + order.custname);
      var mob = (" Mobile :" + order.mobile);
      var loc = (" Location :" + order.location);
      var del = (" Delivery Slot :" + order.slot);

      //this value in the form of table 
      var prod1 = "<div class='cell11'>" + orders[i].items[j].prodcode + "</div>";
      var qty1 = "<div class='cell11'>" + orders[i].items[j].quantity + "</div>";

      var row = "<div>" + cost + mob + loc + del + prod1 + qty1 + "</div>";
      str = str + row;
    }
  }

  var element = document.getElementById("mytable01");
  element.innerHTML = str;
}
```